# Turn off Chrome processes sharing session cookie?

Tags: google-chrome

When I run chrome, it creates a new process for each instance.  Why would each process instance have access to the same session cookie?  Even all the incognito instances share the same session cookie.  How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why would each process instance have access to the same session cookie?

Because *not* sharing the cookie jar would cause nonintuitive behavior -- for instance, if you opened a site in one tab, logged in, then opened a new tab and navigated to that same site, you would be logged out in that tab.

> How can I turn this off?

There are instructions on how you can set up multiple separate profiles here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

As far as I'm aware, though, there's no way to use a separate cookie jar without a whole separate profile.

Comment: This makes sense, but I wish they could provide a simple command line option to disable this like IE does.

Comment: Good answer! But the link is broken it seems. See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

That's ridiculous, that incognito windows share anything. They should be completely separate independent instances. I struggle with this all the time, using multiple admin accounts to administer multiple client accounts, I have to log out of one in order to access another, and back and forth. I would expect that once new instance is created it knows nothing of the other, unlike tabs where I would expect to share it. 
I don't use google accounts in this work, they have nothing to do with google so creating separate profiles is no use since it can be done only with google accounts.

Only way around it is to stop using Chrome.

Comment: Exactly, this is my exact reason for googling this. I need a way to stop cookies being shared so that I can use the same browser to handle multiple "projects" on behalf of different "clients". The only thing I can really think of is making specific google accounts for each client and then switch between the accounts as I need. This in theory should solve the problem but it's just a bit of a pain.