# Multi user safe java web application

Tags: java, jsp, session, web-applications, javabeans

I have an assignment that says to make a game that is multi user safe, though when I run two instances of this application in different tabs of the same browser, they synchronize and become the same game state. Is there any way around this? also, how could i prevent two users loading the same save file as they are stored on the server. I am using Jsp and Servlets to create this application.

EDIT: here my code for my servlet, this does all the operations and all my jsp pages just get the object and display data

```
package can;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SaveLoader extends HttpServlet
{
    public SaveLoader() {}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    HttpSession sesh = request.getSession();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String gameType = request.getParameter("gameType");
    String closeCase = request.getParameter("closeCase");
    String proceed = request.getParameter("proceed");
    String offer = request.getParameter("offer");
    Game game;

    if(username == null && gameType == null && closeCase == null && proceed == null && offer == null)
    {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        return;
    }

    //Parameters coming from homepage
    if(username != null && gameType != null)
    {
        if(gameType.equals("NG"))
        {
            game = new  Game();
            game.setUsername(username);
            sesh.setAttribute("Game", game);
            response.sendRedirect("game");
            return;
        }
        else if(gameType.equals("LG"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
            return;
        }
    }

    if(sesh.getAttribute("Game") == null)
    {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        return;
    }
    else
    {

        //user clicks on case
        if(closeCase != null)
        {
            game = (Game) sesh.getAttribute("Game");
            if(game.getCaseLeft() != 0)
            {
                int closeCaseINT = Integer.parseInt(closeCase);
                closeCaseINT = closeCaseINT - 1;

                Briefcase[] temp = game.getBriefcase();
                temp[closeCaseINT].setOpen(true);
                game.setBriefcase(temp);

                int cases = game.getCaseLeft();
                cases = cases - 1;

                game.setCaseLeft(cases);

                response.sendRedirect("game");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("game");
                return;
            }
        }

        //user clicks on NEXT after opening number of cases
        if(proceed != null)
        {
            game = (Game) sesh.getAttribute("Game");
            if(proceed.equals("nxt") && game.getRoundN() != 5)
            {
                Briefcase[] temp = game.getBriefcase();
                double tempPrize = 0;
                int caseCount = 0;
                double max = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                {
                    if(temp[i].isOpen() == false)
                    {
                        tempPrize += temp[i].getAmount();
                        caseCount++;

                        if(temp[i].getAmount() > max)
                        {
                            max = temp[i].getAmount();
                        }
                    }
                }
                tempPrize = tempPrize / caseCount;
                game.setMaxInPlay(max);
                game.setPrize(tempPrize);

                response.sendRedirect("bank");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Briefcase[] temp = game.getBriefcase();
                double tempPrize = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                {
                    if(temp[i].isOpen() == false)
                    {
                        tempPrize += temp[i].getAmount();
                    }
                }
                game.setPrize(tempPrize);

                response.sendRedirect("end");
                return;
            }
        }

        //bank offer Deal or No deal
        if(offer != null)
        {
            game = (Game) sesh.getAttribute("Game");
            int temp = game.getRoundN();
            temp++;
            game.setRoundN(temp);

            if(offer.equals("NoDeal"))
            {
                game.setPrize(0);
                game.setMaxInPlay(0.0);
                response.sendRedirect("game");
                return;
            }
            else if(offer.equals("Deal"))
            {
                response.sendRedirect("end");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is what all my jsp pages use to get the object

```
<%
  HttpSession sesh = request.getSession();
  Game game = (Game) sesh.getAttribute("Game");

  if(game == null)
     {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        return;
    }
  %>
```

Comment: can you give any code samples? From what you've said, it sounds like your program isn't thread-safe. To give help specific to your problem, you need to give more information.

Comment: Updated with my servlet and jsp scriplet, maybe that will help?

Comment: You are storing stuff in the session which will be unique for each client so there is no problem there. The session is maintained by your browser sending the JESSIONID cookie with each request to the server. Your browser will send the same cookie for each open tab which is what most users would typically want. Try using icognito tabs. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627752/1356423